# Trying to make 3 columns with different things in each one without using a table in CSS HTML

Tags: html, css

Not sure if this can be done. This where I am after many tries.

I want to layout an HTML page down 3 columns, with different kinds of things in each column. I've tried many things and have run out of ideas. Is it that this can only be done in a table?

Or is there a way to arrange the columns like the below sample grid **without changing HTML** using CSS only?

What I want:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| Column left 1|   Column center   | Column right  |
---------------|                   |----------------
| Column left 2|                   |
---------------|                   |
| Column left 3|                   |
---------------|                   |
               |-------------------|
```

What I get:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| Column left 1|   Column left 2   | Column left 3 |
---------------|-------------------|----------------
-------------------------------------
|   Column center   | Column right  |
|                   |----------------
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|-------------------|
```

Here's my last attempt code...

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .column {
      float: left;
      width: 33.33%;
      padding: 10px;
      height: 200px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
    }

    .row:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
```

```html
    <h2>Three Columns</h2>

    <div class="row">
    <div>
      <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
        <h2>Column 1</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
        <h2>Column 1 a</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
        <h2>Column 1 b</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;height: 650px">
        <h2>Column 2</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
        <h2>Column 3</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a task for flexbox. `.row { display: flex; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `display: flex;` this gives you a little more control over how you set up you containers. You can also adjust padding to remove the space between elements.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.column {
  flex: 1;
}
.col-1-cont {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
    <h2>Three Columns</h2>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="column" id="column-1">
      <div class="col-1-cont" style="background-color:#aaa;">
        <h2>Column 1</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1-cont" style="background-color:#aaa;">
        <h2>Column 1 a</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1-cont" style="background-color:#bbb;">
        <h2>Column 1 b</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;height: 650px">
        <h2>Column 2</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc; height: 200px;">
        <h2>Column 3</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Three great answers quickly. God bless SO! A programmers lifeline. I gave your's the solution check because it looks exactly like what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean like having a interactable element (button, href) within the class ````col-1-cont````?

Comment: the-legittdm: No, it's working perfect. I had some CSS conflicts when I first plugged in the code, but that's all worked out and the page looks great. Thanks again for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked a change ONLY in CSS, here is my suggestion: use ****display: flex****. In my opinion, it's the best option. To learn more about it, it's my [favorite link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.row div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

I hope that helps and works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are applying the `column` class to the wrong elements.
You are not telling the wrapper "" of the left column to be a column, but just a normal div (=block element = 100% width).

Try it like this:

```css
   * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .column {
      float: left;
      width: 33.33%;
      padding: 10px;
      height: 200px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
    }

    .row:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
```

```html
<h2>Three Columns</h2>
    
        <div class="row">
        <div class="column"><!-- THIS is the wrapper, that creates the column and should be 33% -->
          <div style="background-color:#aaa;">  <!-- these columns should be the full width in the 33% column, that wraps them and gives them their width -->
            <h2>Column 1</h2>
            <p>Some text..</p>
          </div>
          <div style="background-color:#aaa;">
            <h2>Column 1 a</h2>
            <p>Some text..</p>
          </div>
          <div style="background-color:#bbb;">
            <h2>Column 1 b</h2>
            <p>Some text..</p>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;height: 650px">
            <h2>Column 2</h2>
            <p>Some text..</p>
          </div>
          <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
            <h2>Column 3</h2>
            <p>Some text..</p>
          </div>
      </div>
```